# Определить любое взаимодействие со страницей

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как определить любое взаимодействие со страницей (клик, перетаскивание, скролл и т.д.) и **мгновенно** на него отреагировать.

К примеру, на десктопных, на событие `scroll` функция отзывается мгновенно, а на мобильных, только после окончания прокрутки.

**Итак вопрос:** как одну функцию привязать к нескольким (ко всем возможным) событиям и как сделать так, чтобы при скролле функция отзывалась срузу с началом прокрутки, а не после окончания?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function() {
       $(document).on('click dblclick mouseenter mouseleave и т.д..',
                    handler);

        function handler(e) {
            // в зависимости от e.type обрабатываем
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Genson, спасибо! Очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Как написали выше, вам нужно подписаться на все нужные вам события, но вот с мобильными устройствами ничего не выйдет, событие onScroll всегда будет отрабатывает по завершению.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863547/javascript-scroll-event-for-iphone-ipad — вот тут исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: @RubaXa, спасибо! Ваши ответы как всегда ценны!